# how to get Video id from iframe of youtube in php or cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i have this iframe

```
<iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YRUG-Pu7RzE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

how to get video id from it by regular expression or any.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$subject = '<iframe width=\"425\" height=\"349\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/YRUG-Pu7RzE\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$pattern = '!http://(?:www.)?youtube.com/embed/([^"']+)!i';
$result = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $subpattern);
```

$subpattern will contain:

```
Array ( [0] => http://www.youtube.com/embed/YRUG-Pu7RzE [1] => YRUG-Pu7RzE )
```

Comment: I am not happy with the syntax highlighting. Can this be improved?