# get youtube video id from iframe video

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, youtube

```
<?php echo $videoFirstArray['fileToUpload']; ?>
```

This field contains the ifrmae,something like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ISMzgunUono" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

From this  i want this "ISMzgunUono".I've searched the forum and follwed the link but didn't find the any way to keep my 'fileToUpload' field inside the pregmatch.
Some of the links that i follwed:
[Get YouTube video id from embed iframe code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845089/get-youtube-video-id-from-embed-iframe-code)
and this link gives an error
[how to get Video id from iframe of youtube in php or cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449497/how-to-get-video-id-from-iframe-of-youtube-in-php-or-cakephp)
Expecting replies soon:

Comment: I want the video id from the database field fileToUpload.Php will be better i think,but if possible kindly send the code in JS also for my better understaing of JS

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378286/how-to-get-the-id-from-iframe

Comment: Why didn't this work? https://regex101.com/r/vY6eV7/15

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, in PHP, you should be able to run:

```
preg_match('/youtube.com\/embed\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/', $videoFirstArray['fileToUpload#'], $matches);
if($matches[1]) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

And it should echo `ISMzgunUono`. This is untested, though! Let me know if it works.

Comment: Solved,Thnx for all the help,u all kept me moving in the right direction.The second link from ravi solved the problem

Comment: Thnx to all,you all saved me today,got good comments from my manager.Cheers to all.

Answer (score 3):

With javascript and regular expressions you can do like this:

```js
var url = document.getElementById('myIframe').src,
    regExp = /.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/,
    videoId = url.match(regExp);

if (videoId && videoId[1].length === 11) {
    console.log(videoId[1]);
}
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ISMzgunUono" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php

$string = $videoFirstArray['fileToUpload'];
$pattern = '!youtube.com/embed/([^"]+)!i';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
print_r($match);

?>
```

The expected output should be something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => youtube.com/embed/ISMzgunUono
    [1] => ISMzgunUono
)
```

Btw this was taken by [how to get Video id from iframe of youtube in php or cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449497/how-to-get-video-id-from-iframe-of-youtube-in-php-or-cakephp)